# How to hookup an onError event for an SPTimerjob?

Tags: timer-jobs

I have a timer job which is pretty standard. Like any timer job execution of it can sometimes fail. If this happens in job status (Central Admin) the timer job status is failed.

I would like to be able to catch this type of failure in my job definition and hookup a built in event, such as onFail or onError - is this type of thing possible?

Comment: Can you please specify which SharePoint version are you using? 2010 / 2007?

Comment: SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is either: a) simulate the handler inside the timer job (if this is possible) and then force the timer job status as failed; b) force a second esecution of the timer job with the Retry job definition parameter; c) force the execution of another timer job using the new RunNow job definition method (and leaving the original job in a failed status). I know this isn't much, but at the moment nothing better comes to mind. I will try and search for a more elegant solution (I had a similar problem in the past, so I'm on the same boat here...)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a try { } catch { } block on your Execute function.  In the catch I would have it record the error message to the ULS log (or email you if thats what you want) and then throw the exception.

The ensures you log and/or are notified of the failure but the failure is also seen on the timer job in Central Admin.

So, something like:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    base.Execute(targetInstanceId);
    try
    {
        // Timer Job Code to Execute
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // write to ULS or email
        throw exception;
    }
}
```